# Naming conventions for indices not being adopted. SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, indexing, sqlalchemy

```py
# database.py
POSTGRES_INDEXES_NAMING_CONVENTION = {
    "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=POSTGRES_INDEXES_NAMING_CONVENTION)
```

```py
# schemas.py
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), index=True)

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="items")
```

When I build out the tables and then print out the indices for the given table, I get the following:

- Index('ix_items_id', Column('id', Integer(), table=,
  primary_key=True, nullable=False))
- Index('ix_items_description', Column('description', String(),
  table=))
- Index('ix_items_title', Column('title', String(), table=))
- Index('ix_items_owner_id', Column('owner_id', Integer(),
  ForeignKey('users.id'), table=))

But I am expecting this(*the prefix is what I'm trying to achieve*):

- Index('pk_items_id', Column('id', Integer(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False))
- Index('ix_items_description', Column('description', String(), table=))
- Index('ix_items_title', Column('title', String(), table=))
- Index('fk_items_owner_id', Column('owner_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'), table=))

I did edit the format for the ix value and it did work, so I know the updated naming conventions are being utilized. They're just not working for the other constraint types.

**Versions**

- Python [3.10.5]
- SQLAlchemy [2.0.20]

P.S. I am relatively new to SQL/SQLAlchemy

Comment: Works for me (that is, I see `pk_...` and `fk_...` using `\d` in psql) - how are you printing out the index names?

Comment: snakecharmerb I am printing out in console with Python. But I am using DB Browser tool for SQLite and not seeing it there too.

Comment: Perhaps the `index=True` on `id` and `owner_id` is causing some confusion. _`Indexes`_ are created for these columns because of the `index=True`, but _`constraints`_ are also created, and these constraints have the expected prefixes (try printing the names of the contents of `Item.__table__.constraints`).